# What's the difference between differences? 差 and 違い

Tags: kanji, word-choice

What's the difference between 差 and 違い?  When would I use each?

Which (if either) would I use for describing the difference between something like sample data and the best fitting equation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`違い` simply means "difference".  `差` means difference in the sense of a margin or gap, and seems to relate to things that are calculable.

> [誤差]{ご・さ}　→　Margin of error
> [時差]{じ・さ}　→　Difference in time - (時差ぼけ　→　Jet lag)

It seems like you could replace most instances of `違い` with `差`, but not the other way around.  `差` is definitely more appropriate when talking about sample data, etc.

However, there might be times when the two have distinct meanings.  For example, say you have a boy who is 10 years old, and another who is 20.  `年齢の差` would be "10 years", but `年齢の違い` might describe how the characteristics of their ages differs; like "10-year-olds have more energy, but 20-year-olds are smarter."  Not sure if this is correct, but seems different to me.

Answer (score 10):

I agree in general with istrasci's answer. Just to add, `差` is used particularly for things whose difference is evaluated by the *difference in the mathematical sense* (that is, by subtracting the value of one from that of another). Times and ages are usually compared in this way, so it it appropriate to use `差`.

`違い` is a general term for describing differences. Difference among things that do not have a clear quantity or things that are not evaluated by subtraction is expressed as `違い`. Things like the difference between Picasso and Monet's paintings, which cannot be easily quantitized, or the volume of a sound, which is usually evaluated as magnitude rather than difference, can be expressed as `違い`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use both to denote a "difference" in a casual conversation. E.g. in many contexts, 違いが分からない ＝ 差が分からない. If a person is really nice to your friend and really mean to you, you could say「この（扱いの）差はなんだ……？」. Similarly you could use 差 to describe change, e.g.「一年前との差」. In both cases, you could replace 差 with 違い if you wanted to.

The differences are as follows:

- Only 差 can be used for [mathematical differences, as given here](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%B7%AE-67667) (second definition under さ)
- Only 違い can be used to denote [a "mistake", as given in the second definition here](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%81%95%E3%81%84-559087). However, note that only 差 can be used to denote a calculable "error" in a mathematical/scientific context, e.g.「誤差」= "margin of error".